# Connection to a Mongo database on my disk via MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb

I have a database dataBase at C:MongoDB/data. How do I connect to it via MongoDB Compass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the url and the port that is used when you launch your `mongod` process (default: localhost:27017), and then, configure your MongoDB Compass to contect well to the database. If you use Authentication, just place your username/password and Authentication database in the form